# Customer Register not adding information into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, web

I have a customer register page which when I input text it does not transfer to my database, When a user enters their details I want their details to be entered into my database I have looked over my code and don't notice any errors I might have missed something or forgot something. I was wondering if anyone could help me.

[image: Php Myadmin]

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Marcus","***********","electronicshub",);?>
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
 <?php
  $active='Account';
  include("includes/header.php");
 ?>

<!-- Shop -->
 <div id="content"><!-- #content Begin -->
  <div class="container"><!-- container Begin -->
   <div class="col-md-12"><!-- col-md-12 Begin -->
    <ul class="breadcrumb"><!-- breadcrumb Begin -->
     <li>
      <a href="index.php">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      Register
     </li>
    </ul><!-- breadcrumb Finished -->
   </div><!-- col-md-12 Finished -->
   <div class="col-md-3"><!-- col-md-3 Begin -->
     <?php
      include("includes/sidebar.php");
     ?>
   </div><!-- col-md-3 Finished -->
   <div class="col-md-9"><!-- col-md-9 Begin -->
    <div class="box"><!-- box Begin -->
     <div class="box-header"><!-- box-header Begin -->
      <center><!-- center Begin -->
       <h2> Register A New Account </h2>
      </center><!-- center Finished -->
      <form action="customer_register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><!-- form Begin -->
       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
        <label> Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c_name" required></input>
       </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
        <label>Your Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c_email" required></input>
       </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
        <label>Your Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="c_pass" required></input>
       </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
        <label>Your Country</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c_country" required></input>
       </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
        <label>Your City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c_city" required></input>
       </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
        <label>Your Contact</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c_contact" required></input>
       </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
        <label>Your Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="c_address" required></input>
       </div><!-- form-group Finished -->
       <div class="form-group"><!-- form-group Begin -->
        <label>Your Profile Picture</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" name="c_image" required></input>
       </div><!-- form-group Finished -->


       <div class="text-center"><!-- text-center Begin -->
        <button type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Register
        </button>
       </div><!-- text-center Finished -->
      </form><!-- form Finished -->
     </div><!-- box-header Finished -->
    </div><!-- box Finished -->
   </div><!-- col-md-9 Finished -->
  </div><!-- container Finished-->
 </div><!-- #content Finished -->

<!-- Footer -->
  <?php
   include("includes/footer.php");
  ?>







<script src="js/jquery-331.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-337.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

<?php
 if(isset($_POST['register'])){
  $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
  $c_email = $_POST['c_email'];
  $c_pass = $_POST['c_pass'];
  $c_country = $_POST['c_country'];
  $c_city = $_POST['c_city'];
  $c_contact = $_POST['c_contact'];
  $c_address = $_POST['c_address'];
  $c_image = $_FILES['c_image']['name'];
  $c_image_tmp = $_FILES['c_image']['tmp_name'];
  $c_ip = getRealIpUser();
  move_uploaded_file($c_image_tmp,"customer/customer_images/$c_image");
  $insert_customer = "insert into customers (customer_name,customer_email,customer_pass,customer_country,customer_city,customer_contact,customer_image,customer_ip) values ('$c_name','$c_email','$c_pass','$c_country','$c_city','$c_contact','$c_address','$c_image','$c_ip')";
  $run_customer = mysqli_query($con,$insert_customer);
  $sel_cart = "select * from cart where ip_add='$c_ip'";
  $run_cart = mysqli_query($con,$sel_cart);
  $check_cart = mysqli_num_rows($run_cart);
  if($check_cart>0){
   $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email;
   echo "<script>alert('You Have Been Register Successfully')</script>";
   echo "<script>window.open('checkout.php','_self')</script>";
  }else{
   
   $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email;
   echo "<script>alert('You Have Been Register Successfully')</script>";
   echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem after about 3 hours of debugging it was just a simple error I had forgot one of the values in phpmyadmin and I added it in my code and its all works now.

```
$insert_customer = "insert into customers (customer_name,customer_email,customer_pass,customer_country,customer_city,customer_contact,customer_address,customer_image,customer_ip) values ('$c_name','$c_email','$c_pass','$c_country','$c_city','$c_contact','$c_address','$c_image','$c_ip')";
```